# FFMPEG - Get timestamp from hls stream while downloading

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I need to download a stream, take 1 frames per seconds for image analyse.

I use FFmpeg to take the frames with a pipe to my script.

```
ffmpeg -i XX.m3u8 -vcodec mjpeg -f image2pipe -r 1 -s 1280*720 pipe:1
```

For my analyse, I need the timestamp and  in the HLS we have this data in the m3u8 file  :

```
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-07-31T19:10:12.745Z
#EXTINF:2.000,live
XXXXX.ts
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-07-31T19:10:14.745Z
```

ffmpeg output also something like this

```
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=7.5 size=      59kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate= 480.3kbits/s speed=  36x
```

the problem is that we don't know which second we are downloading

is there a solution to get this timestamp ?
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to parse the m3u8 for that data.

Comment: I suppose, but, how I know if i need to parse the first timestamp or second ?